# How do I upload a gem to geminabox?

Tags: rubygems, geminabox

When I upload a gem to geminabox, what exactly am I supposed to be uploading? Apparently not the `.gemspec` file. When I do that, I get "400Cannot process gem". So what should I be uploading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to upload a `.gem` file.

Comment: When answering your own question, it's best to include all the relevant information so that others stumbling upon your question have an informative answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build the `.gem` file first:

`gem build my-gem.gemspec`

Then run:

`gem inabox my-gem-0.0.1.gem`

Answer (score 0):

Here are the basics to using geminabox:

## Fetch gem:

`gem fetch mygem.gem`

## Add gem to geminabox:

`gem inabox mygem.gem`

## Delete a gem

`curl -s -X "DELETE" -H "Authorization: Basic #{Base64 encoded username:password here}" https://your_geminabox_site.com/gems/mygem.gem`

### Without authentication:

`curl -s -X "DELETE" https://your_geminabox_site.com/gems/mygem.gem`